# How does one reference an unspent transaction output?

Tags: utxo

In a bitcoin transaction the previous unspent transaction outputs are referenced.

How are these referenced?

> Do outputs have unique reference or maybe as
>
> `unique transaction reference` X `output recipient's address (its public key)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each transaction output is uniquely identified by an [**outpoint**](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#outpoint). Outpoints consist of

- `txid`: The unique transaction ID of the transaction that created the output. The txid is the 32-byte sha256d hash of the transaction.
- `index`: The output index (`vout`) that marks the position of the output in that transaction. The output index starts counting at zero and is a 4-byte unsigned integer.

As an arbitrarily picked example, the outpoint

```
e06a3193c6ac49b8dd862baf9bd3561ffe86d65b6e8a9e73ebe1dc91e3ca2978:1
```

refers to the second output of the transaction [`e06a3193c6ac49b8dd862baf9bd3561ffe86d65b6e8a9e73ebe1dc91e3ca2978`](https://www.smartbit.com.au/tx/e06a3193c6ac49b8dd862baf9bd3561ffe86d65b6e8a9e73ebe1dc91e3ca2978) worth 0.001 BTC which was sent to address `1La27vpuDDr9NR1aZ6GpxoJyNYmHT62nRb`.

Comment: First time I heard the word "outpoint". Is it widely used term?

Comment: @sanket1729: It has been around at least since 2011, see e.g. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/2359/5406